# How can I change Google Sheets ownership in bulk?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

I have a ton of Google spreadsheets I want to move to another Google Drive account. I ignorantly downloaded them all, forgetting that Drive converts .gsheet to .xlsx when you download. That means spreadsheets with UDFs, attached forms, or non-Excel functions are mostly changed beyond usability.

As far as I've been able to see, the simplest solution will be to share all the files I want to move with  destination Account B, then make copies there, which will be owned by Account B. But this feels like a big kludge. Is there a better way?

Comment: First share the spreadsheets with the other account, then from the share dialog select the sharing opción for the other account and change it to owner

Answer (score 1):

As Ruben already outlined, the quickest solution should be bulk share and changing ownership of the files.

1. Share the spreadsheets in bulk to this new account of yours.
2. Modify the owner of these spreadsheets to be the new account.
3. Delete them from the old account as desired, or simply unshare them from the new account.